# Permutations of a league schedule

Tags: java, algorithm, permutation

Creating league scheduling software and have a math question that I need a little help wrapping my head around.

Say you have 4 teams(for simplicity) and you check every possible permutation of 1,2,3,4. This permutation is only called the first week which gives you 24 possible permutations.

1,2,3,4 is a permutation and say Week 1 1X4 is a game 2X3 is a game. 
Week Two's combination of game is set via round robin so 4,1,2,3 is up next; 4X3 1X2 are the game.

My question is that if week two's combination of games does not work (because of constraints) but instead an order of 3,4,1,2 would work would this ever be checked by performing the permutation on week 1? i.e. week 1 was 1,2,3,4 week 2 was 3,4,1,2

Or would I need to permute week 1 then permute week 2 and so on and so on to actually get every possible schedule. My gut is telling me that I do actually need to permute every week in order to actually get every possible permutation of the schedule.

EDIT:
I'm asking if there were four weeks would my permutations calculator be 24*24*24*24 not just 24.

Comment: Is there any reason why you would not calculate all permutations, but them in an array, and the remove the ones that don't pass your additional constraints? For the rest I do not really understand your question.

Comment: Yeah at 11 teams you are looking at around 39 million permutations just not feasible.

Comment: How many weeks you need to have scheduled?

Comment: 11 weeks. Basically I permute, test, add if it passes throw it away if not repeat. My question centers on whether I should permute test week 1 permute week 2 test etc or just permute once at thr brginning and go from there

Comment: If game A-B is played in week 1, can game B-A then be chosen for week 2, or is taking turns regarded as the same game, and excluded as a possibility, or is that part of the constraints test?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer your question directly, just checking all permutations for week 1 will not necessarily result in all possible permutations being checked. Test with some simple samples and you'll see that fairly quickly

It looks to me as if you need a standard [Backtracking](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Backtracking) algorithm. These are designed for exactly these types of problems with constraints.

The general form would be something like

```
function permutation
    if all current matches satisfy constraints
        if any weeks remaining to be allocated
            for each possible match for next week
                call permutation with that match added
        else
            accept this solution
```

The assumption is that there are enough constraints that few permutations will be legal. However if many permutations are legal then the process of accepting the solutions will need to take this into account in how they are processed.

Comment: This is how I was thinking in regards to having to call a permutation every week in order to find every possible solution

Comment: What if there isn't enough constraints? To many permutations for memory?

Comment: Yes I don't think you have an alternative. However as long as you use a backtracking algorithm it will prune branches that violate your constraints as early as possible. It also has the advantage of outputting solutions as it proceeds.

Comment: If you actually want to use the legal permutations then you're going to have to tackle storing them somehow. If you just want to count them then there's no problem: 'accept this solution' is just incrementing a variable.

Comment: Alternatively, if you want, say, 100 possible options then you could store them in a list and then exit when the list is full.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I am concerned this solution may help you.
First you take an input that is week from user.After that you compute permutation of week.
And Finally, multiply with power of week.

```
public class Schedule {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter week");
        int x = scan.nextInt();
        int y = (int) Math.pow(permutation(x), x);
        System.out.println(y);
    }

    public static int permutation(int week) {
        int y;
        if (week == 1) {
            return 1;
        } else {
            y = week * permutation(week - 1);
        }
        return y;
    }
}
```

Comment: OP makes reference to constraints. In other words, it's not just a simple combinatorial problem: each combination needs to be examined to determine if a constraint is violated.